Explicit Parallelization of an Exotic Sphere
Milnor's exotic spheres in dimension 7 are parallelizable.
This is a known fact (see this question on MathOverflow for a good discussion and some references). 
My question is whether the explicit form of this parallelization is also known, as it is the case for the ordinary 7-sphere. If not, is there a straightforward way of finding an expression for this vector field? 
Thanks in advance!
